# How to switch base layer based on internet connection availability

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

My application ( html+ JavaScript) use Google map as a base layer. I also setup OSM as an offline base layer to use when there is no internet connection.

Now I'm locking for a way to make app check for internet connection, if there is, then use Google map as a base layer. if not, then use OSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a test that only succeeds when you have a connection, so a way to test that is to request a known good internet resource. If the test fails, you have no connection.

An XMLHttpRequest won't work, because of cross-domain restrictions. What can get around cross-domain restrictions? Images!

For example:

```
var test = new Image();
test.onload = function() { console.log('loaded')};
test.onerror = function() { console.log('error')};
test.src = "http://ds9.ssl.berkeley.edu/imageviewer/images/images2/latest_eit_284_full.jpg";
```